# Excel: Charts for Filtered Ranges are Showing Up Blank

Tags: excel, filter, charts

I have a document that I have built tables of data into that are formula driven. I created charts for these tables and for reporting purposes applied filters to these tables to make the charts more readable. The way this works is the user selects an option from an ActiveX combo box which triggers the filter on the table thus making the chart only display the filtered values. All of this works very well except when I add more data in the form of new row or columns to my table. The result is when you select an option from the combo box the chart just appears blank. This only happens sometimes and I have yet to figure out why. The attached picture is showing what the charts data looks like when I chose select data after this problem occurs. As you can see there is data that should be displayed in the dialogue box but it appears empty, likewise the chart is empty. If I copy and paste the chart the data then appears in the new chart, until I select a different option from the combo box, then it disappears again. Very confusing and frustrating. Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I needed to recalculate the sheet.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Calculate
```

This seems to work fine.